# how to match all punctuation character in VBA regex (such as '\p{P}' in some other language)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to match all punctuation character

I know can use '\p{P}' in PHP or other languages

but, it seems not works in VBA.
I try to use
`pattern = "[.,\x0a\x21\x22\x24\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2d
\x3b\x3c\x3e\x3f\x5b\2\x5d\x5e\x60\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e]"`

but I think this not a good way, Can someone give me some advice? Thank you

Comment: Word and Excel have different "Find" functionality if you mean to search document content. So you shouldn't ask one question for the two different application interfaces. Then I recommend you research using "Find" within each application, starting with the options available in the dialog box. I don't know about Excel, but Word has extended functionality that can search specific character codes; it also has "wildcards" which is as close to RegEx as you can get in the Word interface.

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: @CindyMeister Now the problem is that I want to match **any punctuation mark**, and if I use wildcards (such as  `[\,\.\:\;\{\}\(\)]`. ), I always feel that some of punctuation mark will be missed. may be this Punctuation **`!`** in document, then I can't find it

Comment: Word has no way of specifying "any/all punctuation". You have to *know* what punctuation to inlcude... But the RegEx you show us is no different - that just lists character codes instead of literal characters.